# How to connect Adobe Captivate XApi course with YetAnalytics or LRS (Learning record system)?

Tags: adobe, adobe-captivate, xapi

I am trying to connect my Adobe Captivate XApi course to the LRS (YetAnalytics). I have very less information as to what should i add in this code of tc-onfig.js in the course files:

```
// Pre-configured LRSes that should receive data, added to what is included
 // in the URL and/or passed to the constructor function.
//
// An array of objects where each object may have the following properties:
        //
//    endpoint: (including trailing slash '/')
//    auth:
//    allowFail: (boolean, default true)
//    version: (string, defaults to high version supported by TinCanJS)
//
TC_RECORD_STORES = [
    {
        endpoint : "",
        auth : "",
        allowFail: ,
        version: "",
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should avoid using that functionality. That code is leveraged by an underlying library in Captivate (Rustici Driver) for packages with a `tincan.xml` file. That package will be launched with an LRS endpoint and authentication credential which is where it will send the statements that it generates. Generally it is a much better idea to send all statements to that configured LRS and then figure out a way to get those statements either forwarded from or pulled from that LRS into your additional LRS(s).

This is for two main reasons. First by using this functionality you have to hard code a credential into the package which makes it insecure and indistinguishable during requests, this is generally just bad. Second, there is little to no error handling around calls that leverage this functionality, so if you set `allowFail` to `false` exceptions will go uncaptured and the content will likely behave in strange ways (or break completely), if you set `allowFail` to `true` then you will have no recourse when a call fails and you potentially will not know that you've lost data.

(Unfortunately, I know this because I implemented the functionality originally a very long time ago before fully understanding all of the ramifications.)

But just so I've answered your actual question, if you wish to not heed my advice, then the values that should go there will be passed through to the constructor for a `TinCan.LRS` object which is documented here: http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanJS/doc/api/latest/classes/TinCan.LRS.html

The `auth` being the most tricky, it should be a value that is a full `Authorization` header value as needed to connect to the LRS, very often a Basic Auth header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brian but can you help me out with a detailed version of it as i am very new to this and finding it really difficult to connect with LRS. Also the resources for the same is very less and i haven't seen a step by step solution for this problem.